# How to get this: "If mobile don't run this javascript (purechat ) on shopify"?

Tags: javascript, shopify

I was looking for an answer and have tried many options but nothing worked.

So, I'm trying to disable [Pure Chat](https://www.purechat.com/) if on mobile.

Pure Chat Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
     data-cfasync='false'>

    window.purechatApi = {
      l: [],
      t: [],
      on: function() {
        this.l.push(arguments);
      }
    };
    (function() {
      var done = false;
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.async = true;
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://app.purechat.com/VisitorWidget/WidgetScript';
      document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0).appendChild(script);
      script.onreadystatechange = script.onload = function(e) {
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
          var w = new PCWidget({
            c: 'b935f3c9-9b39-4746-8080-c4b0ac74963d',
            f: true
          });
          done = true;
        }
      };
    })();

</script>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Hiding the box is not sufficient? Do you literally require to not load the script on mobiles?

Comment: Thank you. But where do I put this? In theme, snippet or css? I'm using shopify platform.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting if the page is running on mobile device is a tricky thing to do.
You can read up more about it in a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

If you choose to most upvoted solution, you can achieve what you want the following way:

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) === false) {
    // not mobile device, 
    // initialise pure chat here
}
```

Disclaimer: This solution depends on the user-agent string, which is not the most reliable, since it can be changed easily by user. But in this particular case, it's a reasonable enough solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line in theme.liquid or styles.scss.liquid

`@media (max-width: 799px){.purechat{display:none !important;}}`

Adjust `max-width` as required. This will load the script but will hide it on any screen with less than 800px width.